# Was my edit too drastic, blatantly wrong or actually okay?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I recently submitted [this edit.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10823206) I believe I tried my best to improve the post. The original was full of noise, had some improvements that could be made to the flow and was generally a code dump.

So I removed all the unnecessary code (pretty much all of it), improved the formatting and grammar.

Was my edit too drastic, blatantly wrong or actually okay?

Comment: Here is a good reference guide for making code edits: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code In short, we generally do not make edits to code, outside of formatting

Comment: @CubeJockey That post doesn't discuss removing superfluous code at all.

Comment: @Servy fair enough.

Comment: My C# knowledge is old and rusty at best. Did this edit remove a working example and trim it to a single function or was the code actually unneeded?

Comment: @Andy It removed unnecessary code, seeing as there was no `Graphics` object anyway it wouldn't compile as is with all the code. The only code needed to reproduce was in the event handler that I left alone

Comment: @Andy Personally I'm somewhat conflicted.  Much of the code is certainly superfluous, and you could probably come up with an answer only seeing the edited version, but I could see some of that code helping readers understand what the OP is doing wrong better, and there are also problems with their code that was edited out that is discussed in comments.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder It shows enough code to know that it won't compile.  It doesn't necessary show enough code to demonstrate how the OP should actually be doing what he wants to do.

Comment: @Servy I understand that but aren't comments only temporary anyway? And the comments didn't address the actual question just other things needed to improve the code.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder That doesn't mean they're not adding some value.  Especially considering that the problems they bring up are much more serious, and much harder to fix, than the one the OP specifically asked about.  It's showing that the entire approach the OP is using is flawed.  That's important information to know.

Comment: @Servy I know but they aren't in respect to the question and also would a trimmed down version be better? i.e. removing the unnecessary event handlers?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder And they're not posted as answers, they're comments.  It's an entirely appropriate use of comments.  As I said, with the trimmed down version you can explain why it won't compile, but you can't really explain anything that the compiler errors aren't already telling the OP.  You don't have enough information to know ho to actually *fix* it without more context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a crap question.  It's a crap question before your edit, and it'd be a crap question even after your edit.  It's a code dump with an, "it don't work" at the end.  Whether it's a few dozen lines or three doesn't really change that.  It doesn't contain a description of the problem, it doesn't explain what the program needs to actually do, and as a result one can't really post a *quality* answer about how to address the problems that it has.  On top of all of that, the question is 4 years old.

Just vote to close the question, downvote, and move on.  You're trying to polish a turd.

Comment: Fair enough, just thought itd be worth trying to improve it seeing as it had a reasonably helpful answer

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I don't imagine that this question could ever possibly be useful to another person, even with that answer.  Given the terrible quality of the question, even if someone else *did* make the same mistake, they'd never find that question as it doesn't describe the problem.  And of course, if they did post the error messages, you'd find many thousands of resources out there explaining those error messages.  There is no value here at all.